# how do you model handles to resources of a bigger resource

Tags: rust

I am very intrigued by Rust, but the one thing I cannot wrap my head around is how to handle resources of some larger system.

For example I may have a Graphics context based on some driver system like cuda or vulkan. And now I create resources in that context, memory handles, textures, etc. I will most likely want to "own" these resources somewhere, a scenegraph or whatever. How do I make this safe? I mean, it will likely not be safe to destroy the context before the texture.

Another example would be some kind of pool of things that are expensive to create, or part of something bigger. I take things out of that pool, and when I am done with them they should return to the pool. Also it shall not be allowed to destroy the pool before the objects it hands out.

In the work I do i end up having these things all the time. And have not yet found a solution.

Comment: Hmm, while thinking about this I finally realized I can do this with arc, maybe combined with mutex, and a weak reference from the objects to the pool. But this feels somewhat inefficient for something like a stack allocator, but may be enough for my current problems. Yet the question remains, are high performance, highly local allocators possible in rust? I.e. a simple non-releasing, bounded-size stack allocator in some use cases is blazingly fast, but of course not if you wrap everything with reference counted pointers.

Answer (score -1):

Usually long-lived handles are wrapped in `Arc`, so that they can be stored and passed around freely.